# How to send a post to Facebook friend's wall android SDK 3.0

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I want to post on Facebook friend's wall with (android) Facebook SDK 3.0. How can I do that?

Comment: never use Graph-API for posting on friend's wall. because it is disabled after 6, Feb 2013. FB recommend u to use `Feed Dialog` for posting on friend's or your own wall. this is the link for how to use `Feed Dialog` : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/feed-dialog/

Answer (score 0):

> The Facebook SDK for Android provides a method to let you publish
>   stories from your app to a user's timeline. You can also use this
>   method to post a status update on your user's behalf. This method uses
>   the Graph API, and is an alternative to using the Feed Dialog

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/publish-to-feed/

Comment: You can only use that method to publish to me/feed, not a friend's wall. Since the February breaking changes, you can no longer post to a friend's wall unless you use the Feed Dialog.